# Rubix ML class not found in Laravel project

Tags: laravel, namespaces

I've installed `Rubix ML` using `composer` as specified here: https://docs.rubixml.com/2.0/installation.html

I've created the following code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Rubix\ML\Datasets\Labeled;
use Rubix\ML\Extractors\CSV;
use Rubix\ML\Transformers\TextNormalizer;
use Rubix\ML\Transformers\WordCountVectorizer;
use Rubix\ML\Transformers\TfIdfTransformer;
use Rubix\ML\Persisters\Filesystem;
use Rubix\ML\Classifiers\KNearestNeighbors;
use Rubix\ML\CrossValidation\Reports\MulticlassBreakdown;
use Rubix\ML\CrossValidation\Reports\ConfusionMatrix;
class MLModel {
    public function predict($inputText)
    {
        // Load the trained model
        $modelPath = '/var/www/gdpr/tests/model.rbx';
        $modelData = file_get_contents($modelPath);
        $estimator = unserialize($modelData);

        // Preprocess the input text
        $textNormalizer = new TextNormalizer();
        $wordCountVectorizer = new WordCountVectorizer(10000);
        $tfIdfTransformer = new TfIdfTransformer();

        $inputText = $textNormalizer->transform([$inputText]);
        $inputText = $wordCountVectorizer->fit($inputText)->transform($inputText);
        $inputText = $tfIdfTransformer->fit($inputText)->transform($inputText);

        // Make a prediction
        $prediction = $estimator->predictSample($inputText[0]);

        return $prediction;
    }
}

$mlModel = new MLModel();

echo "Please enter your text: ";
$inputText = readline();
$prediction = $mlModel->predict($inputText);

echo "Prediction: {$prediction}";

?>
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Rubix\ML\Transformers\TextNormalizer" not found in /var/www/myproject/tests/predict.php:23
```

I've checked the `vendor` folder and can see the `TextNormalizer` class within the specified `namespace`.

The file is located in the `(base_path)/tests` folder. I've tried moving the file to the Controllers folder using the controllers namespace, but that didn't work.

Am I missing a namespace or something?

Comment: The file is outside the laravel context. This is just a file placed in the laravel project. Try to add a new laravel command for example. php artisan make:command MyCommand and after that move your code in the handle method. Then use php artisan your-command-signature and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to include this line at the beginning of your code before first "use" statement:

```
include __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```